# PHP Json Malformed When Posted From jQuery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am having a weird issue, when i use json_decode() on some json from a jquery ajax call it's coming back always saying that the json is malformed (JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX).

I say this is weird because if i take a copy of the raw posted json from the developer console and manually push it through json_decode() then it decodes perfectly fine.

I have uploaded a txt file of the example json here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IZ5RkpFK7KLUNYeZe4dPdxGWZXinmFSJ/view?usp=sharing which works manually parsing it but not from posted data. Another weird issue is if i save the json string to a longtext field in a mysql database and then pull it out again, it then decodes fine; but this isn't ideal, it needs to validate it before going to the database and i'm unsure why this would allow it to decode anyway.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Do you have BOM in your file?

Answer (score 0):

This might be happeing due to new line code added in your code. You can add below code and try to decode the code again it might work.

```
$content = preg_replace('/[\r\n\t\s]+/s', ' ', $content);#new lines, multiple spaces/tabs/newlines
$content = preg_replace('#/\*.*?\*/#', '', $content);#comments
$content = preg_replace('/^\s+/', '', $content);#spaces on the begining
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have tried this and afraid it doesn't solve the issue. It still returns null on the data; the data is valid as if i copy it manually from the console it works fine.

Comment: The attachement that you have uploaded is the actual json and you are trying to decode with PHP using json_decode(), correct... ?

Comment: It turns out the posted json is actually adding slashes, when i stripslashes it works!

Comment: Thats great that it worked. However, I have used the same JSON without stripping the slashes on my local system, and it still works.. 

Anyways.. The problem is solved, thats all that matters.